# Angular behaving differently on Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I am building an angular app with several modules close to [john papas styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). Following that, I have several independent modules with their own route definitions and others with interceptors. My Problem is: when I run it on Cordova / Android, state definitions only seem to work, when I put them in the main module. In my Browser the work. Did anybody come over this issue yet?

E.g. this works on both local browser and on device with cordova:

```
//main.js
'use strict';
angular.module('main', [
  'app.core',
  'auth'
])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // ROUTING with ui.router
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/list');
  $stateProvider
    // this state is placed in the <ion-nav-view> in the index.html
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'main/templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'MenuCtrl as menu'
    })
  .state('main.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'pageContent': {
        templateUrl: 'auth/templates/auth.login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
/* more states here */
```

This only works in local browser (main module same as above):

```
//auth.routes.js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('auth.routes')
    .config(config);

function config ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'pageContent': {
          templateUrl: 'auth/templates/auth.login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
}

//auth.module.js
'use strict';

angular.module('auth', [
  'app.core',
  'auth.constants',
  'auth.routes',
  'auth.controllers',
  'auth.services',
  'auth.interceptors',
  'auth.config'
]);

angular.module('auth.constants', []);
angular.module('auth.routes', []);
angular.module('auth.controllers', []);
angular.module('auth.services', []);
angular.module('auth.interceptors', []);
angular.module('auth.config', []);
```

Error says that the state was not found on navigation.

Comment: I guess this is because of the example, but in your 2nd code portion you're not defining "main" state, only its child "main.login". Could that be the problem?

Comment: In the example code you are overriding previously defined auth.routes module with this line angular.module('auth.routes', []);. That could be the problem too.

Comment: i am defining it not overwriting

Comment: @Cyberdelphos: the main module stays the same as noted

Comment: What about the duplicated lines of  `use strict` - maybe that leads to a problem?
You could also go ahead and put an IIFE around each angular.module delcaration according to the styleguide you mentioned
`// logger.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('logger', logger);

    function logger() { }
})();`

Comment: use strict is in different files. I can say that minification is no problem, as i am testing unminified on cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
angular
        .module('test', [])
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                title: 'Calculators',
                templateUrl: 'modules/views/login.html',
                controller: ''
            });
    }
```

remove state provider ,check for simple routing it will work.

Comment: I can not confirm that it works. I tried with stateprovider only as my project relies on it. But you may have pointed me to an interesting direction.